Php Curl, returns jibberish, but when viewing in browser and view source, it is raw html. I need the raw html
I need access to the raw html which I can get by opening the url in a browser and view source.  However when I try to use php and curl I get jibberish.  I know that there is a fairly simple solution but I just don't know what that is.
This is the url that I am trying to curl:
http://streetfoodfinder.com/embed/BowzersHotDogStand/calendar/small?d=7&amp;u=BowzersHotDogStand&__cf_chl_rt_tk=M7C3__P7LdOQgsBholCQLZViGZ_C5I3Z5fRz67U0N7g-1735601660-1.0.1.1-fHtNkfe7yezbiI5paU96zDuN5NAuDeaL9_eb22Z0U04

This is the html that I get back when I curl the url with php:
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><title>Just a moment...</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><style>*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0}html{line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;color:#313131;font-family:system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Arial,Noto Sans,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol,Noto Color Emoji}body{display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:100vh;min-height:100vh}.main-content{margin:8rem auto;max-width:60rem;padding-left:1.5rem}@media (width <= 720px){.main-content{margin-top:4rem}}.h2{font-size:1.5rem;font-weight:500;line-height:2.25rem}@media (width <= 720px){.h2{font-size:1.25rem;line-height:1.5rem}}#challenge-error-text{background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:contain;padding-left:34px}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){body{background-color:#222;color:#d9d9d9}}</style><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="390"></head><body class="no-js"><div class="main-wrapper" role="main"><div class="main-content"><noscript><div class="h2"><span id="challenge-error-text">Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue</span></div></noscript></div></div><script>(function(){window._cf_chl_opt={cvId: '3',cZone: "streetfoodfinder.com",cType: 'interactive',cRay: '8fa844e9396c7bb9',cH: '5kHEi3YIzviaCfYijWr6Gs7FAw0dPOMDk8tbBwTEYv0-1735627132-1.2.1.1-RVW7kZs2a6PsY7jEPP3z7.OG.o7K4bUrbd33JpZ.LwhSN97HuNNUUXby0w2MGGu5',cUPMDTk: "\/embed\/BowzersHotDogStand\/calendar\/small?d=7&amp;u=BowzersHotDogStand&__cf_chl_tk=agJsStwGO2vh6sBuUK9I0P9YanuyvpZryQnsesCBjEE-1735627132-1.0.1.1-D1OUf1zi1zWtUIeg01pU_7o.VozMCxR4s9kDAJXrd74",cFPWv: 'b',cITimeS: '1735627132',cTTimeMs: '1000',cMTimeMs: '390000',cTplC: 0,cTplV: 5,cTplB: 'cf',cK: "",fa: "\/embed\/BowzersHotDogStand\/calendar\/small?d=7&amp;u=BowzersHotDogStand&__cf_chl_f_tk=agJsStwGO2vh6sBuUK9I0P9YanuyvpZryQnsesCBjEE-1735627132-1.0.1.1-D1OUf1zi1zWtUIeg01pU_7o.VozMCxR4s9kDAJXrd74",md: "fWx1FNY1389koEzlD09voi3QRHuXyin.rGsBpUnFj7Y-1735627132-1.2.1.1-R.gVoIHPkbQBlILJlsEDY38Al8_h6KWyC4E4jorwOnFXwUeRohQj296zvFOxQywjGnKQaf1Doxc0WI0SlYa8bmYShkfJrAJmwKu4PxdJsjXMDlHb2Adw91FNx1OBJmdYVfR9cqzUlnNpLbKQYchaz3fNFT6ZUC25BfbsiIt.qNWmJFqMi6krk_ukbGUN0G1opOg1qHZlIo9ODK1PSLdGkWOsO4kYaCbIEC6dVV_TgvL3tp5fXstYlD510Q6jhf0BhFknXIDztE.vVmSZRdQ3wt09cOwQPw7Khw3M5CqE_6bZrOAQA0lWePdZLEFTPBTgHCE13cNyKWNtDk0UC2Ra9SyJL2jyfUFp8Man5VMXltgL65qK0r0fBJyEDHuiC3cv7be8SsJX9N5xA.69fsH3qZuADSHgqqjT3NwGpnWxbfBqlus41JBLOK7jc0cD4nlZpMgt.v.YAQvxNjUqMtcSlJfuAHTdoGuKwLy_OhaCTqr1z1cfFy7HPPiIjimYzq9kdh6.Uf_HKmFVuy8PIjTRXVSjPIh0lntE9lDTaP2AAIhtEtoHx3gT6wpvCrmbRIMd3WXn0vZeB0sLEvH1C7hrCAUGo6ZAv4CXmscGK2f2xjpy7_8PfbHdChogE8ryCuU8ICVLr5ZbI_WSN.wX3hI1KgUERfhv.30Ohz9HCNrsfY8a2k04F6ai2p5ELjsEEqlA4Ot5aLiYqAHsTCvIc56JkzLxUleHAtfjvb31A7_xJWMdwD0sWskZ6I.mpkUmZEwdOyQuFkca8GfdinQ_i_cQQWMcHYYHuWPWVW4MaZ3o7TbzhZyru738.0RAMQ9SHhLJqkjjctDIiT2TeLSZ9b_UgpfaLs_4uBjUf.FcKhQYq6i1_7SbFg0MvaCkEY5q3A.X4W8LO0me_F5PY.63nJfyFPODdzQaIeuw5zgVIaIkmX67I3_n7mWD8M9tJwnxmUt2KZjzQYNSWLtWh_oh0OlnUfU5Vrl5RQuBKxJkFijwr6uglaaxbX1Nj98CBWeqGV_.17daWATTVzS9jvZE8pBX05X43KEw..I03kqnZtIge2Ok1C2R7d9OJKYFJIcQ5FSmYZkdCuEPTBamJSrlKjTUyLxhP2Ja6s78Aqc15vw3s2Sy6s6kz0FUZydwgfq2fI.25sY.rJlvvxOYJqjzKL_g8F5ZlfHU7z5rzPUpn8sTbXNb2wldtKEq6Txsg0bJ6TxlbCn5qQnmB.aOVAyLDVc8xPjwde1hWlrwQVJ_l_olB8ps2dgYnMQt.y5W6XPWzV3n6y4mz1NHHDSF5bu2PrhYwSan9q8Y8PK6MWYOHAVxq7XuG8fAiT2M64UfaDgD0wnEPV3LCJnhLInb2zvHfrpjc.7yd3xn_B0.tV.qgdImT4y4muTEUOSnC0gJWXMdKnHqCyA_egCba.BW4ToNcWvLs569SBeLcPRQWyzOF5V5ym5DMWv.ptGLnF7Xm7a2Z_s236GBpRqc5ZEw48XnwxhmOa.5djK6NI9z0RwLFgvvCpcUtqQpBVc2ymr04W3ebjVR9gBPf7Q9ibrp3Mn.AyhaFPZDsts4HdXwZwcRdp9nk.fk0GxfR1T1zco0Elnnnscz5o8PTItFFJA2hlMLRv1ZGEKGIfmZ.vlyt4yGxfUZJxlrGJ15ykECGOu.FKKy70rkJUVKKmoCPbBeP9jh.QcYIuQSFgkMPyL8yTYNdUprpVrZUhi.ltvOi8ZPCXURzSdK6QSkEqDlEVUiEsCnsaMuFCqeYPdaEsbLJG3Z4eb6i5MV1wDcr6tc9lS5YIfXkC1uepV76hx0n5n9APEaus1hIRC9NdolKQtbjcXHjAaLzmZPYEjDJy6DRp7cAE5vocliw7wsJszwIy60KQA5QER8byO37Qen24Jueimd.0X0aFss2MZw_0CQn2N7GRy.luDJLiSWIizobEBxZ6D1E4YdwkoXqq0ssgy4oJpwNxaYScU",mdrd: "zLV6YTdLyVM3ZBUouikigwfzLzyPq385jvr_cHRsAHE-1735627132-1.2.1.1-Srlal8bvsu0MnSU79kdap03q2ynkfPO6xYA2PtlXL9HGuBaV39SNtFIqXnMYuUIszC5hhQOE2fmTVcfkWeEr5GCCMFBzwjG3nQaXvLV2nHPSyHr8TrBZMVMHYolYPeo0JnB1lXxi1fg658I0isa0oGVf7Ek8JBxovZD1upipjuJdwf4ZbMtFnBUlXifx3XfQ4sVzAk_hTcL5qC2GmCgl1Vrcdhn31l1GF6kC0IcxtavhxvzZ6Bn8Yaojuq1KuGp9GrbUlsBPE9BxLRCmrVa27UVvmS27FpdfZMG0oJuePlHDNo1_HIW5.aWEaOOl0uud9iwUzFzd3J7cs63Ofy19EbRE7MQyDeCjnL5IApKSJ2JsOW5O3amKGNWYs05xI_cPPkX1amOwrRMr_pyU8MJHInWgH88caGgnVzx5IoEZMxbsKXJKAx4HanbnX_aAfUD9CAovSP6Uh3s2OHcx1myXvI.Zu1SRsO2ofgRbvR__NOd.kkYtda1ur_lUvJAla04O.BeTQV1zOqHbhRSKyCVuhfgejRoKtiR6VwpDKeicGNAEqdKi6KZphbbCOuArnJKTOkVjnXA0Va8JCB_SmfwwFvoWd5xJ0TaHkfPpaCi5LnZf2I4thg9RDEz8b47gA39DzRvMZE8rQaCwk6Cy4twbgHBq36MramxOqsDjhzFpsyXx6SPKe8FQK0VLIpJ4s_w8_M3ucS8yZ6JSoa1IJATcGxIbR6GRQvWPn1GXSYn0HappM9O8lGQ__rXElRMaqssnWeKBIQ9L8F7asuEJsUrlsTsB.Z7MDdZ_LVszfXXl__gMcXQD1j6.ubD5HnZMfkdQ0S2IlqyKRa3iR74Itkkws0dqYjrm_lC.d5TlyEX0BbFVTPlUpOTLHOL2n4YcgxFJ9vSX5pRW49GmieMdG1ohaGC79IZE7V8Mpjv0Arz6fQDJNRMuDQgs45OBFJqiAYEbKbq_y45_vZ4CcSlODTmcQH0m0YVUofA6xkaRWjh.MEt8GE3rFX8SVIka4zbkF_ZK0HcN5CVZVcImNphCKVgHDE1ZiMdySU1B5PuUfgX7aV4bzE5eex6vq9Z8KLe25se2KefzuvXa0_gsKAgf0j3LSOJPH2kcmZd86aTL2ZzTyG6ASLojcAUAbs4jErYnErkkK31kgzn0b9AE2tWzULyVtpw_7U72RqvygceCsvAS.FMcnn71fbnpyekTZgM.3zGa_i19CtZN0T3Tk7ERi0B2prdBZTJUUjzZjTJJuApEjZ4iKGICuK3LJ77yFWYit8UvoMQr.BGMSk3m2jsuZfO4tgMfoUA.X6HGUg_tuA.2QtiAnT09TyqMtBt3CgWcDuiHgsi8AyFosp6aYTz.9.2z5WPxTAygkK9A_M_scNRLjLY5eGsWnhwnAAelK9npWgO8JeEKVViQN5h7Qvl7gMEQe9p3Ts322t.5NRQe2FxzZ_9wUte9tiTFN4lfbYrdk05kCu0AYJCGMFDPZEBGiV9VFk6VwTPND6KTttDawtLJj6j.CNZzK1s0IpAaMbUoXdL.3HeHt07i8HS1HpoC5Dolm4PPeJdCc2VkSPTupbWIgmNRFT8XcwMXxqoGg_5QC1Ud_2cE_ZmHj1kSNH.vpSpQOYrxGmSu2o24YoNahbJljVRyxLJoAL9_pmk4GijTtrHFeHO8vx6FEC_Pga8SECSimX2yVO99RgDlRwLRkMTPHrJ1mFEycGlWG05uAhhKKtc3SCseN1xmrZTZKCwzAvQaDUv0OrGtgkVrt4IckP5WqD6csCdtHkZWuNkCjMg4TAlkrmjvfAXhm.B0ZDU0wr0Zc6NjlKuhseZCflbeCOw7YythhtLTC8TC1urxUvnBFsRQHfYorrWLs8OW7Tgd8BAy9O4oL1qaGBHdSPDn_UpY94IHkMzJbB1om3X0RUBmJ642w8mT6Enkk4m2rsKLx9tnJuD2rMZWYNGdvpCtOxKe0YVwCpOcHryKRMcyL7X0Gc2UB7yHaavli.0kjIflPsJO0JnGgGv0bBfdj0QVa.zVPUbBz58bwxwwjSB2aGxDR3wJ0zHiG13.R5YJ9oHM5ysVbem2AigUxcDBQmq3tijY9nCComV23MBHGYbV5qiaG9UCcDVqF4sRYWpimaYUOGxbgKW3qvN1tHwk_J7B6C_hhNyEbDCqoCKdB9XGLbkCZT3YaGgek7pf5ttK1_rOlFAyH120bkwfnieX79Q3sWpiJ00MgdzoldW8DmJGzxeJBIP9tiPePqIUUXHP3nId4OunFqCnnqxooejSbVWnn2Ug4weqEbREtGdky_qhaVAbXY_qOZu9DhPlgts_7PF06aJrjt858IRowk6wmn7gXjoAUS4sJSQNGgWin_CyeXWQc91NEx_LuJLFCGmMTiSn0Acd.HV_H0CF1d1.fmKKLW44UjE"};var cpo = document.createElement('script');cpo.src = '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/orchestrate/chl_page/v1?ray=8fa844e9396c7bb9';window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.slice(0, location.href.length - window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;history.replaceState(null, null, "\/embed\/BowzersHotDogStand\/calendar\/small?d=7&amp;u=BowzersHotDogStand&__cf_chl_rt_tk=agJsStwGO2vh6sBuUK9I0P9YanuyvpZryQnsesCBjEE-1735627132-1.0.1.1-D1OUf1zi1zWtUIeg01pU_7o.VozMCxR4s9kDAJXrd74" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);cpo.onload = function() {history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);}}document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);}());</script></body></html>

The html that I am looking to get, which is what you get when you go to the url directly and view source is:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bowzers In Motion Upcoming Events / Schedule</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size: 13px;
            line-height: 1.42857143;
            color: #333;
            background-color: #2A95D3;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        a{
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:hover{
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        ul{
            border: 0;
            margin: 0;
            outline: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 100%;
        }

        small{
            font-size:0.9em;
            display:block;
        }

        #tinyheader{
            background-color: #2A95D3;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            height:45px;
            font-size:16px;
            padding-left:8px;
            font-weight:bold;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            line-height:1.4;
            padding-top:5px;
            border-bottom:2px solid #2A95D3;
        }

        #tinyframe{
            background:#FFFFFF;
            border-color: #2A95D3;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
            overflow:hidden;
            border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
            border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
        }

        .list li{
            padding:4px;
            padding-left:8px;
            background:#FFFFFF;
            border-bottom:inset 1px #DDDDDD;
            color:#2a2a2a;
        }

        .list li a{
            color:#2a2a2a;
        }

        #tinyheader a{
            color:#FFFFFF;
        }
        #tinyheader a:visited{
            color:#FFFFFF;
        }

        #tinyfooter a{
            color:#FFFFFF;
        }
        #tinyfooter a:visited{
            color:#FFFFFF;
        }

        .section_header{
            background-color: #666 !important;
            color:#fff !important;
            height:13px;
            line-height: 1;
        }

        .ename{
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        .etime{
            font-size:0.9em;
            font-weight:500;
        }

    </style>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            //window.setInterval(function(){console.log(window.innerHeight)}, 5000);
            function sizer(){
                //$('#tinyframe').height(window.innerHeight);
                $('#tinyscroller').height(window.innerHeight - $('#tinyheader').outerHeight() - 4);
            }
            $(window).resize(sizer);
            sizer();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tinyframe">
        <div id="tinyheader" style="">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://streetfoodfinder.com/BowzersHotDogStand">
                Bowzers In Motion
                <div style="font-size:0.75em;font-weight:400;">Upcoming Schedule</div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="tinyscroller" style="width:100%; overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden">
            <div id="tinycontent">
                <ul class="list">
                    
                        
                        
                            
                                
                                <li class="section_header">Today (12/31)</li>
                            
                            <li>
                                <a target="_blank" href="https://streetfoodfinder.com/BowzersHotDogStand#3255472">
                                    <div class="ename">Standardized Brewing</div>
                                    <div class="etime"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 10am-2pm</div>
                                    <small class="eaddy">
                                        5920 Evans Farm Dr Suite A<br/>
                                        Lewis Center, OH 43035
                                    </small>
                                    
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        
                            
                                
                                <li class="section_header">Saturday (1/4)</li>
                            
                            <li>
                                <a target="_blank" href="https://streetfoodfinder.com/BowzersHotDogStand#3259845">
                                    <div class="ename">3657 E Main St</div>
                                    <div class="etime"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 11am-6pm</div>
                                    <small class="eaddy">
                                        3657 E Main St<br/>
                                        Whitehall, OH 43213
                                    </small>
                                    
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tinyfooter" style="display:none;height:0px; background-color:#2A95D3; font-size:12px;text-align:right;padding-right:5px;">
            <a href="https://streetfoodfinder.com/BowzersHotDogStand">View Bowzers In Motion's Calendar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>(function(){function c(){var b=a.contentDocument||a.contentWindow.document;if(b){var d=b.createElement('script');d.innerHTML="window.__CF$cv$params={r:'8fa849ffde2522c7',t:'MTczNTYyNzM0MC4wMDAwMDA='};var a=document.createElement('script');a.nonce='';a.src='/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/scripts/jsd/main.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(a);";b.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(d)}}if(document.body){var a=document.createElement('iframe');a.height=1;a.width=1;a.style.position='absolute';a.style.top=0;a.style.left=0;a.style.border='none';a.style.visibility='hidden';document.body.appendChild(a);if('loading'!==document.readyState)c();else if(window.addEventListener)document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',c);else{var e=document.onreadystatechange||function(){};document.onreadystatechange=function(b){e(b);'loading'!==document.readyState&&(document.onreadystatechange=e,c())}}}})();</script><script defer src="https://static.cloudflareinsights.com/beacon.min.js/vcd15cbe7772f49c399c6a5babf22c1241717689176015" integrity="sha512-ZpsOmlRQV6y907TI0dKBHq9Md29nnaEIPlkf84rnaERnq6zvWvPUqr2ft8M1aS28oN72PdrCzSjY4U6VaAw1EQ==" data-cf-beacon='{"rayId":"8fa849ffde2522c7","serverTiming":{"name":{"cfExtPri":true,"cfL4":true,"cfSpeedBrain":true,"cfCacheStatus":true}},"version":"2024.10.5","token":"5c6abbb0d35147c59a350371cd4e0154"}' crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

What am I not doing right?

PHP cURL cannot obtain the DOM structure dynamically loaded by JS. If you want to obtain the "final" DOM structure, use something like Selenium WebDriver to mimic a user to browse the website.

The HTML you get contains: "Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue".

I get jibberish...no, it's still html. It isn't nonsense. It's just not the html you were expecting- as mentioned in the comments above this is a bot protection mechanism used by cloud flare. The owners of the site clearly don't want you to scrape their content...perhaps it's copyrighted or something? Do they have an API you can legitimately use instead, perhaps?

Yes I know it's still html, but not useable html, so it's jibberish.  Yes they have a widget code that I can throw on my site.  However it does not blend or match my site content and they don't give you much control on changing the the content like size and colors.  It is very very limited, so I thought that I could use curl and then parse it out to make the changes to the look so that way it matches my design and flow.

Most people like their content to be shown using their layout and branding - that way, people know where it's from. The way you're doing it, you'd be passing off the content as your own, and I'd guess the original owners of it wouldn't be very happy about that.
